# How to fill the color gradually on drawn view canvas Android

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-custom-view, waveform

I am having a WaveFormView on which I want to change the color of it while playing Audio file and as the Audio is paused it should be stopped coloring at that certain point and when resumed it should continue forward with coloring. I am not getting how to do it in my code..

[image]

This is the screen shot of my generated waveform. Now when I will click on Play button it should change the color of waveform gradually with red color (from start to end slowly).

Here is my code to draw waveform view.

***WaveFormView.class***

```
public class WaveformView extends View {
public interface WaveformListener {

    public void waveformFling(float x);

    public void waveformDraw();
}

;
// Colors
private Paint mGridPaint;
private Paint mSelectedLinePaint;
private Paint mUnselectedLinePaint;
private Paint mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint;
private Paint mBorderLinePaint;
private Paint mPlaybackLinePaint;
private Paint mTimecodePaint;

private SoundFile mSoundFile;
private int[] mLenByZoomLevel;
private double[][] mValuesByZoomLevel;
private double[] mZoomFactorByZoomLevel;
private int[] mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel;
private int mZoomLevel;
private int mNumZoomLevels;
private int mSampleRate;
private int mSamplesPerFrame;
private int mOffset;
private int mSelectionStart;
private int mSelectionEnd;
private int mPlaybackPos;
private float mDensity;
private float mInitialScaleSpan;
private WaveformListener mListener;
private GestureDetector mGestureDetector;
private ScaleGestureDetector mScaleGestureDetector;
private boolean mInitialized;
Color color;


public WaveformView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);

    // We don't want keys, the markers get these
    setFocusable(false);

    mGridPaint = new Paint();
    mGridPaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    mGridPaint.setColor(
            getResources().getColor(R.color.grid_line));
    mSelectedLinePaint = new Paint();
    mSelectedLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    mSelectedLinePaint.setColor(
            getResources().getColor(R.color.waveform_selected));
    mUnselectedLinePaint = new Paint();
    mUnselectedLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    mUnselectedLinePaint.setColor(
            getResources().getColor(R.color.waveform_unselected));
    mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint = new Paint();
    mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint.setColor(
            getResources().getColor(
                    R.color.selection_border));
    mBorderLinePaint = new Paint();
    mBorderLinePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mBorderLinePaint.setStrokeWidth(1.5f);
    mBorderLinePaint.setPathEffect(
            new DashPathEffect(new float[]{3.0f, 2.0f}, 0.0f));
    mBorderLinePaint.setColor(
            getResources().getColor(R.color.selection_border));
    mPlaybackLinePaint = new Paint();
    mPlaybackLinePaint.setAntiAlias(false);
    mPlaybackLinePaint.setColor(
            getResources().getColor(R.color.playback_indicator));
    mTimecodePaint = new Paint();
    mTimecodePaint.setTextSize(12);
    mTimecodePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mTimecodePaint.setColor(
            getResources().getColor(R.color.timecode));
    mTimecodePaint.setShadowLayer(
            2, 1, 1,
            getResources().getColor(R.color.timecode_shadow));

    mGestureDetector = new GestureDetector(
            context,
            new GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener() {
                public boolean onFling(
                        MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float vx, float vy) {
                    mListener.waveformFling(vx);
                    return true;
                }
            });

    mSoundFile = null;
    mLenByZoomLevel = null;
    mValuesByZoomLevel = null;
    mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
    mOffset = 0;
    mPlaybackPos = -1;
    mSelectionStart = 0;
    mSelectionEnd = 0;
    mDensity = 1.0f;
    mInitialized = false;
}

public boolean hasSoundFile() {
    return mSoundFile != null;
}

public void setSoundFile(SoundFile soundFile) {
    mSoundFile = soundFile;
    mSampleRate = mSoundFile.getSampleRate();
    mSamplesPerFrame = mSoundFile.getSamplesPerFrame();
    computeDoublesForAllZoomLevels();
    mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
}


/**
 * Called once when a new sound file is added
 */
private void computeDoublesForAllZoomLevels() {
    int numFrames = mSoundFile.getNumFrames();
    int[] frameGains = mSoundFile.getFrameGains();
    double[] smoothedGains = new double[numFrames];
    if (numFrames == 1) {
        smoothedGains[0] = frameGains[0];
    } else if (numFrames == 2) {
        smoothedGains[0] = frameGains[0];
        smoothedGains[1] = frameGains[1];
    } else if (numFrames > 2) {
        smoothedGains[0] = (double)(
                (frameGains[0] / 2.0) +
                        (frameGains[1] / 2.0));
        for (int i = 1; i < numFrames - 1; i++) {
            smoothedGains[i] = (double)(
                    (frameGains[i - 1] / 3.0) +
                            (frameGains[i    ] / 3.0) +
                            (frameGains[i + 1] / 3.0));
        }
        smoothedGains[numFrames - 1] = (double)(
                (frameGains[numFrames - 2] / 2.0) +
                        (frameGains[numFrames - 1] / 2.0));
    }

    // Make sure the range is no more than 0 - 255
    double maxGain = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
        if (smoothedGains[i] > maxGain) {
            maxGain = smoothedGains[i];
        }
    }
    double scaleFactor = 1.0;
    if (maxGain > 255.0) {
        scaleFactor = 255 / maxGain;
    }

    // Build histogram of 256 bins and figure out the new scaled max
    maxGain = 0;
    int gainHist[] = new int[256];
    for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
        int smoothedGain = (int)(smoothedGains[i] * scaleFactor);
        if (smoothedGain < 0)
            smoothedGain = 0;
        if (smoothedGain > 255)
            smoothedGain = 255;

        if (smoothedGain > maxGain)
            maxGain = smoothedGain;

        gainHist[smoothedGain]++;
    }

    // Re-calibrate the min to be 5%
    double minGain = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while (minGain < 255 && sum < numFrames / 20) {
        sum += gainHist[(int)minGain];
        minGain++;
    }

    // Re-calibrate the max to be 99%
    sum = 0;
    while (maxGain > 2 && sum < numFrames / 100) {
        sum += gainHist[(int)maxGain];
        maxGain--;
    }

    // Compute the heights
    double[] heights = new double[numFrames];
    double range = maxGain - minGain;
    for (int i = 0; i < numFrames; i++) {
        double value = (smoothedGains[i] * scaleFactor - minGain) / range;
        if (value < 0.0)
            value = 0.0;
        if (value > 1.0)
            value = 1.0;
        heights[i] = value * value;
    }

    mNumZoomLevels = 5;
    mLenByZoomLevel = new int[5];
    mZoomFactorByZoomLevel = new double[5];
    mValuesByZoomLevel = new double[5][];

    // Level 0 is doubled, with interpolated values
    mLenByZoomLevel[0] = numFrames * 2;
    mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[0] = 2.0;
    mValuesByZoomLevel[0] = new double[mLenByZoomLevel[0]];
    if (numFrames > 0) {
        mValuesByZoomLevel[0][0] = 0.5 * heights[0];
        mValuesByZoomLevel[0][1] = heights[0];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i < numFrames; i++) {
        mValuesByZoomLevel[0][2 * i] = 0.5 * (heights[i - 1] + heights[i]);
        mValuesByZoomLevel[0][2 * i + 1] = heights[i];
    }

    // Level 1 is normal
    mLenByZoomLevel[1] = numFrames;
    mValuesByZoomLevel[1] = new double[mLenByZoomLevel[1]];
    mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[1] = 1.0;
    for (int i = 0; i < mLenByZoomLevel[1]; i++) {
        mValuesByZoomLevel[1][i] = heights[i];
    }

    // 3 more levels are each halved
    for (int j = 2; j < 5; j++) {
        mLenByZoomLevel[j] = mLenByZoomLevel[j - 1] / 2;
        mValuesByZoomLevel[j] = new double[mLenByZoomLevel[j]];
        mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[j] = mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[j - 1] / 2.0;
        for (int i = 0; i < mLenByZoomLevel[j]; i++) {
            mValuesByZoomLevel[j][i] =
                    0.5 * (mValuesByZoomLevel[j - 1][2 * i] +
                            mValuesByZoomLevel[j - 1][2 * i + 1]);
        }
    }

    if (numFrames > 5000) {
        mZoomLevel = 3;
    } else if (numFrames > 1000) {
        mZoomLevel = 2;
    } else if (numFrames > 300) {
        mZoomLevel = 1;
    } else {
        mZoomLevel = 0;
    }

    mInitialized = true;
}

public boolean canZoomIn() {
    return (mZoomLevel > 0);
}

public void zoomIn() {
    if (canZoomIn()) {
        mZoomLevel--;
        mSelectionStart *= 2;
        mSelectionEnd *= 2;
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
        int offsetCenter = mOffset + getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        offsetCenter *= 2;
        mOffset = offsetCenter - getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        if (mOffset < 0)
            mOffset = 0;
        invalidate();
    }
}

public boolean canZoomOut() {
    return (mZoomLevel < mNumZoomLevels - 1);
}

public void zoomOut() {
    if (canZoomOut()) {
        mZoomLevel++;
        mSelectionStart /= 2;
        mSelectionEnd /= 2;
        int offsetCenter = mOffset + getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        offsetCenter /= 2;
        mOffset = offsetCenter - getMeasuredWidth() / 2;
        if (mOffset < 0)
            mOffset = 0;
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
        invalidate();
    }
}



public double pixelsToSeconds(int pixels) {
    double z = mZoomFactorByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel];
    return (pixels * (double)mSamplesPerFrame / (mSampleRate * z));
}



public void setListener(WaveformListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

public void recomputeHeights(float density) {
    mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = null;
    mDensity = density;
    mTimecodePaint.setTextSize((int)(12 * density));

    invalidate();
}


protected void drawWaveformLine(Canvas canvas,
                                int x, int y0, int y1,
                                Paint paint) {
    canvas.drawLine(x, y0, x, y1, paint);
}


@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    if (mSoundFile == null)
        return;

    if (mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel == null)
        computeIntsForThisZoomLevel();
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    int height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    int widths = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    // Draw waveform
    int measuredWidth = getMeasuredWidth();
    int measuredHeight = getMeasuredHeight();
    int start = mOffset;
    int width = mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel.length - start;
    int ctr = measuredHeight / 2;



    Log.e("wid",String.valueOf(width));
    Log.e("widCal",String.valueOf(mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel.length));
    Log.e("widstart",String.valueOf(start));


    if (width > measuredWidth)
        width = measuredWidth;


    Log.e("measured",String.valueOf(measuredWidth));


    // Draw grid
    double onePixelInSecs = pixelsToSeconds(1);
    boolean onlyEveryFiveSecs = (onePixelInSecs > 1.0 / 50.0);
    double fractionalSecs = mOffset * onePixelInSecs;
    int integerSecs = (int) fractionalSecs;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < width) {
        i++;
        fractionalSecs += onePixelInSecs;
        int integerSecsNew = (int) fractionalSecs;
        if (integerSecsNew != integerSecs) {
            integerSecs = integerSecsNew;
            if (!onlyEveryFiveSecs || 0 == (integerSecs % 5)) {
                canvas.drawLine(i, 0, i, measuredHeight, mGridPaint);
            }
        }
    }

    // Draw waveform
    for ( i = 0; i < width; i++) {
        Paint paint;

        if (i + start >= mSelectionStart &&
                i + start < mSelectionEnd) {
            paint = mSelectedLinePaint;
            //   paint.setColor(color);
        } else {
            drawWaveformLine(canvas, ((widths/width)*i), 0, measuredHeight,
                    mUnselectedBkgndLinePaint);
            paint = mUnselectedLinePaint;
        }
        drawWaveformLine(
                canvas, ((widths/width)*i),
                ctr - mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                ctr + 1 + mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
                paint);





        if (i + start == mPlaybackPos) {
            canvas.drawLine(i, 0, i, measuredHeight, mPlaybackLinePaint);
        }
      }


    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.waveformDraw();
    }
}



private void computeIntsForThisZoomLevel() {
    int halfHeight = (getMeasuredHeight() / 2) - 1;
    mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel = new int[mLenByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel]];
    for (int i = 0; i < mLenByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel]; i++) {
        mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[i] =
                (int)(mValuesByZoomLevel[mZoomLevel][i] * halfHeight);
    }
}

    }
```

**MainActivity.class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements WaveformView.WaveformListener {


    WaveformView mWaveformView;
    SoundFile mSoundFile;
    private float mDensity;
    private File mFile;
    private String mFilename;
    private long mLoadingLastUpdateTime;
    boolean mLoadingKeepGoing;
    boolean mFinishActivity;
    private ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    String mTitle,mArtist;
    private Thread mLoadSoundFileThread;
    private Thread mRecordAudioThread;
    private Thread mSaveSoundFileThread;

    private boolean mIsPlaying;
    private SamplePlayer mPlayer;
    private String mInfoContent;
    private int mWidth;
    private int mMaxPos;
    private int mStartPos;
    private int mEndPos;
    private boolean mStartVisible;
    private boolean mEndVisible;
    private int mLastDisplayedStartPos;
    private int mLastDisplayedEndPos;
    private int mOffset;
    private int mOffsetGoal;
    private int mFlingVelocity;
    private int mPlayStartMsec;
    private int mPlayEndMsec;
    private Handler mHandler;

    Button pla;
    MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    boolean ismIsPlaying;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        pla = (Button)findViewById(R.id.play);
        mWaveformView = (WaveformView)findViewById(R.id.waveform);
        mWaveformView.setListener(this);
        mHandler = new Handler();

        Uri uri = Uri.parse("/sdcard/audio_file.mp3");

        mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mediaPlayer =  MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),uri);

        loadGui();
        loadFromFile();

    }


    /**
     * Called from both onCreate and onConfigurationChanged
     * (if the user switched layouts)
     */
    private void loadGui() {
        // Inflate our UI from its XML layout description.
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
        mDensity = metrics.density;



        mWaveformView = (WaveformView)findViewById(R.id.waveform);
        mWaveformView.setListener(this);



        if (mSoundFile != null && !mWaveformView.hasSoundFile()) {
            mWaveformView.setSoundFile(mSoundFile);
            mWaveformView.recomputeHeights(mDensity);

        }

    }

    private void loadFromFile() {

        mFilename = "/sdcard/audio_file.mp3";

        mFile = new File(mFilename);

        SongMetadataReader metadataReader = new SongMetadataReader(
                this, mFilename);
        mTitle = metadataReader.mTitle;
        mArtist = metadataReader.mArtist;

        String titleLabel = mTitle;
        if (mArtist != null && mArtist.length() > 0) {
            titleLabel += " - " + mArtist;
        }
        setTitle(titleLabel);

        mLoadingLastUpdateTime = getCurrentTime();
        mLoadingKeepGoing = true;
        mFinishActivity = false;
        mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(MainActivity.this);
        mProgressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_HORIZONTAL);
        mProgressDialog.setTitle("Loading...");
        mProgressDialog.setCancelable(true);
        mProgressDialog.setOnCancelListener(
                new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener() {
                    public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                        mLoadingKeepGoing = false;
                        mFinishActivity = true;
                    }
                });
        mProgressDialog.show();

        final SoundFile.ProgressListener listener =
                new SoundFile.ProgressListener() {
                    public boolean reportProgress(double fractionComplete) {
                        long now = getCurrentTime();
                        if (now - mLoadingLastUpdateTime > 100) {
                            mProgressDialog.setProgress(
                                    (int) (mProgressDialog.getMax() * fractionComplete));
                            mLoadingLastUpdateTime = now;
                        }
                        return mLoadingKeepGoing;
                    }
                };

        // Load the sound file in a background thread
        mLoadSoundFileThread = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    mSoundFile = SoundFile.create(mFile.getAbsolutePath(), listener);

                    if (mSoundFile == null) {
                        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                        String name = mFile.getName().toLowerCase();
                        String[] components = name.split("\\.");
                        String err;
                        if (components.length < 2) {
                            err = getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.no_extension_error);
                        } else {
                            err = getResources().getString(
                                    R.string.bad_extension_error) + " " +
                                    components[components.length - 1];
                        }
                        final String finalErr = err;
                        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                            public void run() {
                                showFinalAlert(new Exception(), finalErr);
                            }
                        };
                        mHandler.post(runnable);
                        return;
                    }
                    mPlayer = new SamplePlayer(mSoundFile);
                } catch (final Exception e) {
                    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    mInfoContent = e.toString();
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                        }
                    });

                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            showFinalAlert(e, getResources().getText(R.string.read_error));
                        }
                    };
                    mHandler.post(runnable);
                    return;
                }
                mProgressDialog.dismiss();
                if (mLoadingKeepGoing) {
                    Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {
                            finishOpeningSoundFile();

                          }
                    };
                    mHandler.post(runnable);
                } else if (mFinishActivity){
                    MainActivity.this.finish();
                }
            }
        };
        mLoadSoundFileThread.start();

    }

    private void finishOpeningSoundFile() {
        mWaveformView.setSoundFile(mSoundFile);
        mWaveformView.recomputeHeights(mDensity);

        Log.e("sound file",mFilename);
        Log.e("sound", String.valueOf(mSoundFile));


    }



    /**
     * Show a "final" alert dialog that will exit the activity
     * after the user clicks on the OK button.  If an exception
     * is passed, it's assumed to be an error condition, and the
     * dialog is presented as an error, and the stack trace is
     * logged.  If there's no exception, it's a success message.
     */
    private void showFinalAlert(Exception e, CharSequence message) {
        CharSequence title;
        if (e != null) {
            Log.e("Ringdroid", "Error: " + message);
            Log.e("Ringdroid", getStackTrace(e));
            title = getResources().getText(R.string.alert_title_failure);
            setResult(RESULT_CANCELED, new Intent());
        } else {
            Log.v("Ringdroid", "Success: " + message);
            title = getResources().getText(R.string.alert_title_success);
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .setTitle(title)
                .setMessage(message)
                .setPositiveButton(
                        R.string.alert_ok_button,
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                                int whichButton) {
                                finish();
                            }
                        })
                .setCancelable(false)
                .show();
    }

    private void showFinalAlert(Exception e, int messageResourceId) {
        showFinalAlert(e, getResources().getText(messageResourceId));
    }

    @Override
    public void waveformTouchStart(float x) {

    }

    @Override
    public void waveformTouchMove(float x) {

    }

    @Override
    public void waveformTouchEnd() {

    }

    @Override
    public void waveformFling(float x) {

    }

    @Override
    public void waveformDraw() {
        mWidth = mWaveformView.getMeasuredWidth();
        if (mOffsetGoal != mOffset) {
            // updateDisplay();
        }
        else if (mIsPlaying) {
         //   updateDisplay();
        } else if (mFlingVelocity != 0) {
       //     updateDisplay();
        }
    }

    private long getCurrentTime() {
        return System.nanoTime() / 1000000;
    }

    private String getStackTrace(Exception e) {
        StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
        e.printStackTrace(new PrintWriter(writer));
        return writer.toString();
    }


    public void buttonClick(View view) {

        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mediaPlayer.start();
        ismIsPlaying = true;


    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please provide some sort of screenshot "how it looks now", "how it should look". Or could you please explain what behavior you have not and what exactly you want to change in it. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelSpitsin please check the update.

Comment: create a new Paint object with red color. In your onDraw() use this new paint for that lines that are in the area of already played wave form.

Comment: @Chris623  can you please explain further ??

Answer (score 0):

In your `onDraw(Canvas canvas)` add the following lines

```
if (i + start <= mPlaybackPos) {
    Paint mPaint = new Paint(paint);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    drawWaveformLine(
            canvas, ((widths/width)*i),
            ctr - mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
            ctr + 1 + mHeightsAtThisZoomLevel[start + i],
            mPaint);
}
```

add them above the line:

```
if (i + start == mPlaybackPos) {
```

And if this works, consider to allocate the Paint-object outside the `onDraw()` method.

Comment: try again, have changed something

Comment: i think it is working buti am not able to set the playback please check my main acitivity updated above

Comment: what problem do you exactly have in the main activity?

Comment: I want to change the color gradually when I click on play but it is not working

Comment: is your test toast showing on button click? Do you hear the music?

Comment: you are playing the music using the mediaPlayer. But your WaveFormView class does not know at which position the playback is at the moment.
So what you should do now is to use a timer or something similar and inform the WaveFormView about the new position

Comment: can you tell how can I do that ?

Comment: Ringdroid waveform in full width according to width of mobile screen